# What is the differential equation for pressure in a container with an orifice?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, ideal-gas, flow

I've seen similar problems all over physics.SE and other sites. Most of the time it is about non-compressible fluids, or not about the differential equations. The physical system of interest is comprised as follows:

A rigid container with a gas at temperature $T_1$, pressure $p_1$ and with volume $V_0$. This rigid container has one hole to the surrounding environment. The temperature $T_r$ and pressure $p_r$ of the surrounding environment is constant.

**Given that $p_1$ is greater than $p_r$ at $t=0$, what is the change of $p_1$ with $t$?**

I assume the following:

- We have an [ideal gas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas)
- It is an isothermal process (Is this even a good assumption?)

Here is a sketch:

[image: Sketch]

My problem is, I can't even construct a differential equation for this system. I thought I could derive one by simply using the following two equations:
The ideal gas law,
$$ p_1V_0 = n R T_1, $$
and the volume flow rate through the orifice, which I assume is 
$$ \frac{dV}{dt} = K\Delta p = K ( p_r - p_1 ),$$
with $K$ as a constant which represents the geometry of the orifice.

**Edit**: I think I made an error here. The last equation is only applicable for incompressible fluids.

I tried to get a differential equation for $n$, the number of molecules in mole which are in the container, by substituting $V$ with $\frac{m}{\rho}$ and $m$ with $Mn$:
$$ \frac{d}{dt}V = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{M n}{\rho}$$
But $\rho$ is also depend on $t$ so, there is nothing won here.

Am I on the right track? I do think I have to incorporate the [Bernoulli's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle) for compressible fluids, but than again, I do not know how.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but, since I find it attractive, I just try to help. So, I don't think that it is a good idea to work an equation for volume. The volume for the gas is always the volume of the container, isn't it? I understand that you try to find the change in the pressure of the gas remaining in the container. Am I wrong? One more thing: no, it doesn't seem that we have a Bernoulli-type problem here. The gas in the container, essentially, is not a flowing gas.

Comment: Yes, since it is rigid, there is no volume change of the container. However - you will have a flow of molecules out of there - which is proportional to the [mass flow rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_flow_rate), out which you can calculate a volume flow rate. And yes, the ultimate target is to calculate $p(t)$ for any $t$.

Comment: @JohnHK I would be pleased to continue the talk with you, but some half an hour later. Will you be available?

Comment: Yes, I will be online.

Comment: I apologize for letting you wait much more. And still I have some things to do. I will return to you, though, some later.

Comment: Now I am with you. Are you online?

Comment: I have a few questions/comments. The flow through the hole seems to me a minor leakage. Shall we consider therefore that for not long intervals of time $T$ and $P$ in the container remain stable. Or, alternatively, shall we consider that the leakage is so slow that there is time for $T$ and $P$ to come to a stable value all along the leakage?

Comment: See my answer below, but regarding a more direct way to solve as a 1 dimensional flow problem, you do need Bernoulli's equation since it deals with the energy loss across the orifice (pressure drop)

Comment: Regardless of the size of the hole, the relationship between pressure drop and flow through the hole is generally quadratic, coming from the $V^2$ term in Bernoulli's equation.

Comment: @Sofia - Yes, I think we can assume that the flow rate is not high. But then again, Im interested in the change of $p_1$ so I do not know how I could apply that.

Comment: @docscience Ah, okay! Does this also apply to a small cylindrical pipe? I've read about [the Hagen-Poseuille equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation#Poiseuille.27s_equation_for_compressible_fluids) for compressible fluids, and they have a $p_1^2 - p_r^2$ term for the volume flow rate.

Comment: @JohnH.K. Yes - if the pipe is relatively short relative to the diameter you can treat it like an orifice. For longer pipes and more viscous fluids Poiseuille's equation may provide a more accurate model. Keep in mind these are all models and only approximate true behavior. George Box said something like "All models are wrong - but some are useful"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very simple way to solve this problem is by using an electrical circuit analogy where your rigid container with a compressed fluid would be represented by a charged capacitor (voltage equivalent to pressure) and the hole in the container as a resistor that's connected to the capacitor with the other end at a voltage equivalent to the pressure on the outside of the container.

Since you're willing to assume ideal gas in an isothermal process as gas expands through the orifice, the relationship between container pressure and the volume of fluid molecules in the container is linear: $P_1 = V/C$. Here $V$ is not $V_o$ ,the container volume, but rather the volume of gas molecules at $p_r$ that were used to charge the pressure in the container to pressure $P_1$. The pneumatic equivalence of capacitance is 'compliance' and that can be determined using the container volume: $C = V_o/p_r$.

With the two elements you have two equations,

The pressure in the container

$$p_1(t)={1\over C} \int Q(t)dt$$

and the pressure drop across the orifice

$$p_1(t) - p_r = Q(t)^2R$$

where $Q$ is the volumetric flow through the orifice, which is equivalent to current in the electrical circuit.

and the volume that leaves the container at pressure $p_r$ is

$$V(t) = \int Q(t)dt$$

Solving the second of these equations for $Q$ and substituting into the first, then solving for $p_1$ gives you the differential equation you need.

Comment: BTW a good reference for solving your problem is "The Analysis and Design of Pneumatic Systems" by Blaine Andersen

Comment: I probably should have also noted that the nonlinear first order differential equation you get does not have a closed form solution. But you can solve it numerical or run it in simulation if you have a stiff solver.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the explanation, a question: Shouldn't $C = V_0/p_r$, as you have written a sentence before?

Comment: @JohnH.K. you are very welcome - and thanks for catching my error! I've fixed it.

Comment: @docscience : I saw your answer, it's appealing, but I have doubts. Doesn't the leakage perturb the thermodynamic equilibrium in the container? I think it does. In the region close to the hole, the gas pressure changes locally, and the change propagates deeper and deeper into the container. The temperature looses meaning. As long as the leakage continues, i.e. there is not yet a thermodynamic equilibrium between the gas in the container and the environment, I don't see that we can speak of pressure and temperature in the container. These are concepts valid at equilibrium. (see continuation)

Comment: @docscience : this is why I question the analogies that you propose. The pressure P analog to the voltage V. But V is well defined at any time during the flow of the current through the resistor. Is P in the container also well defined during the leakage? It doesn't seem so, as I said above. I would have proposed the diffusion equation, but I know nothing about a diffusion through a hole. And the main thing, the pressure is not a well defined concept during the leakage. I suggest to post some additional questions and get help, before giving a final response to John's questions. What you say?

Comment: @JohnH.K. : I regret a lot for yesterday and I apologize. Now, I suggest to read my comment to docscience's answer. I have some doubts. I read your answer that the flow rate may be considered low. But, for highlighting my doubts, during the leakage through the hole, the concept of pressure in the gas is not well defined. There is a lowered pressure near the hole, and the pressure changes as we advance deeper and deeper into the container. So, er can't speak of a pressure in the container because it is not uniform. But, please read my comment to docscience.

Comment: @Sofia Yes - the simple model I've proposed does have its limitations. It's a 'lumped' parameter model that lumps the entire space of the container into a single parameter called compliance, and the energy loss across the orifice into a single parameter called resistance. There is really no component of space involved in this model. It only considers the time evolution of I guess what you might call the quasi-static pressure of the container. It assumes no thermodynamic affects - temperature is constant and there is no heat gain or loss. (continued)

Comment: @Sofia So to do this you need a partial differential equation - like Navier-Stokes. But if you are just looking for a close approximation of how $p_1$ evolves over time and the ratio $p_1/p_r$ is not too large ( so energy losses do not lead to local thermal effects) then the lumped parameter model (electric circuit analogy) works quite well. I use it all the time in modeling the behavior of flow and pressure in intensive care ventilation. The models fit the actual data very well!

Comment: @docscience : is the temperature constant? John is not sure of that. I assume for simplicity that the gas in the container is of the same type as in the environment, otherwise there should be a two-directional flow though the orifice, and John doesn't mention that. Anyway, when the gas in the container will reach the outside pressure, it will reach the outside temperature. Just imagine in the environment a fictive container of the same volume. In the end, both the fictive and real container will contain the gas at the same pressure. Then, why not the same number of moles and same temperature?

Comment: @docscience (cont.) in the end, the container and the environment will reach **full* thermodynamic equilibrium, pressure and temperature, and that because of the entropy (2nd thermodynamic principle) that won't let the degree of disorder in the container to differ from that outside. Don't you think so? I am not good at thermodynamic, I am just trying to reason together with you for the benefit of the person who asked.

Comment: So, from what I gather, for the "1D"-Case / electrical analogy to work, I have to assume $T_1$ = $T_r$. If I want a more accurate physical model, I would have to go with the navier-stokes equations. However, for them, the geometry also has to be accurately described and it is much more time-consuming to handle. I think for a first approximation, I will go with the electrical analogy. Thanks to you two again!

Comment: @JohnH.K. I'll answer your last question, and also hope to answer Sofia's. The effects of temperature changes and heat/gain loss are not included in this electric circuit analogy for expanding gas from the orifice of a container under pressure. So yes you would just assume $T_1 = T_f$. The software used in computational fluid dynamics can consider 1D, 2D or otherwise 3D finite element mesh of space and to each element the Navier-Stokes equations are applied, and the output sets up the boundary conditions of mass, pressure, temperature for the adjoining elements. And at some point (continued)

Comment: @JohnH.K. ... the elements reach the boundaries of your apecified flow boundaries. Depending on the scope of the problem, the 3D calculations can take hours if not days to solve by even fast computers. But their advantage is they give you precise evolution of events at nearly every point in space - if that's what you need. But say you just need an approximate time of how long the container will take to empty. The analogy will give that to you in a small fraction of a second. George Box ... "some are very useful"